# Type '{ match: any; }' is not assignable to type '(props: RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>) => ReactNode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am new to react typescript.
  I wrote this code.

```
interface faceMatch<P> {
  params: P;
  isExact: boolean;
  path: string;
  url: string;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Link to="/sch/h">2</Link>
        <Route path={"/sch/:schProd"} render={({ match: faceMatch<{ schProd: string }>}) => <Home match={match}/>} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

const Home:FC<{ match: faceMatch<{ schProd: string }> }> = ({ match }) => {
  return (
    <div>
     100
    </div>
  );
}
```

in line

```
<Route path={"/sch/:schProd"} render={({ match: faceMatch<{ schProd: string }>}) => <Home match={match}/>} />
```

I get this error 
Type '{ match: any; }' is not assignable to type '(props: RouteComponentProps) => ReactNode'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dunno if your type is correct or wrong but inline props are described like this:

```
<Route path={"/sch/:schProd"} render={({ match} : {match: faceMatch<{ schProd: string }>}) => <Home match={match}/>} />
```

Comment: It seems to work, but I get a warning [cod](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-kare-2jm4n).

Comment: @Squanchy well, read your warning. It's telling you that your match is defined as `schProd` but Home expects a `product`. Make them identically named